# How I can solve this differentiable equation? I don't understand a process to solve it.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hy guys I'm trying solve this equation, but i don't get it, because i don't understand a process to solve it , when a arrive in this part  a don't know how to do the final. Anyone can help me, thanks!

My try:
![Image]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9qGn.jpg]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9qGn.jpg%5D)

The equation is : y'' + y = f(t) ; y(0)=0 ; y'(0)=1  and

f(t){ 1 ,0 <= t <3pi

{ 0 , 3pi <= t < infinity

Equation:
![Image]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7mn4.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7mn4.png%5D)

Comment: Use MathJax for formatting

Comment: I got a slightly different expression for $y(s)$ after taking the Laplace transform. You should use partial fraction decomposition on the fractions with more complex denominators.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piecewise nature of $f(t)$ motivates us to use Laplace transformations.
Using the Heaviside function, we have that $f(t)=1-u(t-3\pi)$

Laplace transform both sides to get
$$s^2Y-1+Y=\frac{1-e^{3\pi s}}{s}$$
$$(s^2+1)Y=\frac{1-e^{3\pi s}}{s}+1$$
$$Y=\frac{1-e^{3\pi s}}{s(s^2+1)}+\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$
Note that $\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+1}\right)=\sin t$
Using partial fraction decomposition we get
$$\frac{1}{s(s^2+1)}=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$
So we have that
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\frac{1-e^{3\pi s}}{s(s^2+1)}\right)$$
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{s}{s^2+1}-\frac{e^{3\pi s}}{s}+\frac{se^{3\pi s}}{s^2+1}\right)$$
$$1-\cos t-u(t-3\pi)+u(t-3\pi)\cos(t-3\pi)$$
$$1-\cos t-u(t-3\pi)-u(t-3\pi)\cos(t)$$
Combining these two results, we get
$$y=\sin t+1-\cos t-u(t-3\pi)(1+\cos t)$$